# Lua Wrapper for C#?

Tags: c#, lua, embedding

I am looking to embed Lua into my C# application and i thought there was a wrapper around the lua API for C#, but don't remember what it is. Can someone point me in it's direction?

Comment: Multiple results on http://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+lua

Comment: If you are using lua for scripting in C# you may also consider runtime C# code compilation. It's more powerful than lua, easy to implement and deliver the same "non-hardcoded" scripting behavior.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe [LuaInterface](http://luaforge.net/projects/luainterface/) is the most popular one for C#.  If I'm wrong, I'm sure someone will correct me.

There's a little more information (from Lua's developers) on integrating Lua and .NET, [on the Lua website](http://www.lua.inf.puc-rio.br/post/8).

**Update:**
As of April 2013, the primary developer [announced that the project was stalling](https://code.google.com/p/luainterface/) due to other committements, and has pointed new developments to [NLua](https://github.com/NLua/NLua) instead.

Comment: lablua isn't *the* lua website but is pretty much the hub for all lua/CLR integration