# Filter a List of objects during debugging in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I have a `List<Student>` that contains lets say 500 students. When I enter **debug mode** on a breakpoint is there a way to filter/search for a student?

I don't want to write code for this check as below:

```
List<Student> students = data.GetStudents();
//break here and filter for student in debug mode
var myStudent = students.Where(k=>k.StudentNumber=="S12312");
```

Is it is not possible in Visual Studio 2013 to do this, I think it would be a great feature to add...

Comment: Yes, it would be nice if LINQ expressions could be evaluated by the debugger e.g. in the immediate window.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't for feature requests. The use of lambdas in the debugger is scheduled for [VS 2015](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/12/11/better-together-c-6-and-the-visual-studio-2015-debugger.aspx).

Comment: You might also find this interesting [Creating lambda expression from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857871/creating-lambda-expression-from-a-string)

Answer (score 7):

Read this post debugging feature is now supported by visual studio 2015: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/support-for-debugging-lambda-expressions-with-visual-studio-2015.aspx

Check debugging option as per this image : http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-45-92-metablogapi/0882.image_5F00_thumb_5F00_13C96B25.png

Comment: Was hoping it is available in VS 2013

Comment: 404: both links are dead. Shame it wasn't inlined here.

Answer (score 2):

You must install VS 2015
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/support-for-debugging-lambda-expressions-with-visual-studio-2015.aspx

Old versions does not support this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a 3rd party debugging tool called [OzCode](http://www.oz-code.com/) (disclaimer: I work for the company that makes it, though I don't work on the product myself).

It extends the QuickWatch debug window to allow searching within the object, looking for strings and values in all the object's properties. It's not a full lambda, but it lets you run a search several levels deep to find a value:

[image]

Comment: Very cool. Going to give it a try.  It seems to add more value than just searching, it also improves usability of debugging in general.