# ASP.NET Web API 2: return filtered list based on Func<> as input parameter?

Tags: c#, lambda, asp.net-web-api2, func

In my ASP.NET Web API 2 project I have a `IHttpActionResult` returning a list of all the cars from my database like so:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetAllCars()
{
    var cars = _carService.GetAllCars();
    if (cars.Count < 1) return Content(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "No cars were found in database");
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, cars);
}
```

And in my data access layer I have a override of the method `GetAllCars()` that takes a `Func<Models.Car, bool>` to filter the list like so:

```
public List<Domain.Car> GetAllCars(Func<Models.Car, bool> filter)
{
    List<Domain.Car> cars = new List<Domain.Car>();
    foreach (var car in _context.Cars.Where(filter).ToList())
    {
        cars.Add(new Domain.Car
        {
            Id = car.Id,
            Make = car.Make,
            Model = car.Model,
            Year = car.Year,
            RegistrationNumber = car.RegistrationNumber
        });
    }
    return cars;
}
```

Now I want to write an `IHttpActionResult` to which I can pass a filter. For example I want to be able to get only a list of cars, which Year property is greater than 1990 like this `c => c.Year > 1990` (could be passed as a string). But is this the way to go about this? Ofcourse I could just retrieve all cars, and then filter the list on my frontend. But if I had 10.000 cars and needed to filter down to 3 cars, then this would be a bad idea.

How would I go about this?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want your controller (or downstream code) to create a func based on query string filters on the request uri?

Comment: @Jaya My question is whether it would be a solution to pass the filter i.e. `c => c.Year > 1990` as a string to the Web API controller, and then pass that string to the `GetAllCars(Func<Models.Car, bool> filter){...}` of my data access layer.

Comment: Can you just directly use the lambda-expression inside your `IHttpActionResult` ? Or are they separated by web call thus need to be serialized first?

Comment: RonRonDK, what you want to do is **Reflection**, you want to compile code at run time, I think the price you will pay is too much to solve a simple problem. You may want to consider using **Dynamic SQL** instead, but if need to go the reflection way, this article will help you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857871/creating-lambda-expression-from-a-string

Comment: Have a look at using odata: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/martinkearn/2015/03/10/using-odata-query-syntax-with-web-api/

Comment: @peco, not exactly the way I was looking for. But the result is. I am still looking for an answer to my original question though.

Comment: @ThariqNugrohotomo I tried to pass the lambda-expression directly, but the `GetAllCars()`couldn't convert the parameter from a string to a `Func<Models.Car, bool>` obviously. Anyway I am going with OData which @peco advised. And it works like a charm so thank you.