# run c# script in windows task scheduler?

Tags: c#

So I'm new to C# and programming and just wrote my first C# script. So now how do I run it? Do I just save it as a .bat file and run it that way? Ultimately, I want to schedule this to run via windows task scheduler.

Comment: C# script? As far as I know, there are no C# interpreters - you need to compile your program into an executable. How have you written your C#? What IDE are you using?

Comment: What's the output type of the assembly you created? DLL or EXE?

Comment: I wrote it in Visual Studio Console Application...sorry for the wrong lingo...

Comment: What file extension is your output?

Comment: Then build your application and find the compiled *.exe in the "Debug/Release" directory.

Comment: found it but it opens up as an XML config file

Comment: There are several files. There is a `.config` file with the name of the program, and also a `.exe` - that's the executable.

Answer (score 1):

You mean a C# program, not script, right? Just use a console application project, and call it (the executable) from scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer combining C# with script languages, here are some options:

- Powershell: [How to run PowerShell scripts from C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C)
- Lua:        [Lua Wrapper for C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283641/lua-wrapper-for-c)
- IronPython: [Embedding IronPython in a C# Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/53611/Embedding-IronPython-in-a-C-Application)